# Firebase phone authentication failed to build after flutter upgrade

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

My flutter application failed to build after flutter version upgraded to flutter 2

Errors:
[image]
my pub get result

/Users/sulfy/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in myflutterapp...

```
Because firebase_auth >=1.0.1 depends on firebase_auth_web ^1.0.1 which depends on http_parser ^4.0.0, firebase_auth >=1.0.1 requires http_parser ^4.0.0.
And because dio 3.0.10 depends on http_parser >=0.0.1 <4.0.0 and no versions of dio match >3.0.10 <4.0.0, firebase_auth >=1.0.1 is incompatible with dio ^3.0.10.
So, because myflutterapp depends on both dio ^3.0.10 and firebase_auth ^1.0.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because myflutterapp depends on both dio ^3.0.10 and firebase_auth ^1.0.1, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

please suggest me a fix, should I remove dio ? or is there a workaround to fix this?

The error above appeared after I have updated my firebase_auth to latest version as my login form with phone number Authentication showed error as follows

```
Undefined class 'AuthCredential'.  Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'AuthCredential'.
```

my phone authentication code is as follows

```
     FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
              phoneNumber: phone,
              timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
              verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential credential) async {
//error: Undefined class 'AuthCredential'.
             
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
    
                UserCredential result = await _auth
                    .signInWithCredential(credential)
//error: The method 'signInWithCredential' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'.
                    .then((value) => null)
                    .catchError((e) {
                  // print('User Exist');
                });
    //error: Undefined class 'UserCredential'.
                User user = result.user;
//error: Undefined class 'User'.
    
                if (user != null) {
              //redirect user
                } else {
                  // print("Error");
                }
                
              },
              verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception) {
              },
              codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) { },
              codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
              //
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specified version of http_parser in your pubspec.yaml, you can try remove this line and then run flutter pub get.

In the case that above doesn't solve the issue can try with this:
https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides